# iOS memory leak with dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

I'm currently profiling my app and coming across a few leaks. I've tried releasing objects all over the place where I think they are needed. Each release has crashed the app.

Here's one line that I think is the culprit:

```
NSDictionary *dicUserData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self forKey:@"chapter"];
```

Just wondering the best way to deal with this. I'm having issues with other leaks too that are kind of similar. It's worth noting that self is a custom class [Dal_Chapter].

Do I need to implement copy or something, call that in the above line and do autorelease on that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Profile your code with zombies enabled.

Comment: You may aswell just call [self retain] instead of [self copy], but this is VERY WRONG.

Comment: How did you find out you have leaks?

Comment: I haven't fixed this yet. I am putting it aside for a few days as I have a few other items to look at. I will post here and try get a correct answer up when I have more time. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using convenience methods such as dictionaryWithObject provide an autoreleased instance of the dictionary object. Unless you're retaining it elsewhere this is not where your leak is.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the static analyser it should be able to point out your leaks for you.

That dictionary will retain self so you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Is the owner of self releasing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you don't have to do anything whith your dictionnary, but if you want to take control of the memory you'll need to do this :

```
NSDictionary *dicUserData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:yourObject forKeys:key];
```

and int your dealloc method,

```
[dicUserDate release];
```

But normaly you just have nothing to do... Are you sure that your leak come from your dictionnary ?

Answer (score 0):

always keep all variables release in dealloc method. is it not in proper place it may be crash .check this link [click here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)